# How can I change tableAdapterManager update order to Delete, Insert than Update in Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the tableAdapterManager there is a property to change the update order to UpdatInsertDelete or InsertUpdateDelete but How can I change tableAdapterManager update order to Delete then Insert, and then Update?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no boolean that causes this. I see two options:

1. Write a stored procedure that does this and point the Update method of the TableAdapter to the stored procedure. Set the UpdateCommand property of the Tableadapter to an SqlCommand object that calls the stored procedure. The UpdateCommand property uses the same syntax as the [SqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand.aspx)
2. Add a method to the TableAdapter that does this in C#.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: @sovantha, of what? The stored procedure?

Comment: @sovantha, I added to my answer. I can't write your stored procedure for you because I don't know enough details. The link to the UpdateCommand property should help you on your way.

Comment: @sovantha, no problem, that's what we're here for ;)